# Responsive Design: Everything shrinks when mobile keyboard is active

Tags: android, html, css

There are many screen resolutions in browsers nowadays, so using `px` in my CSS sizes isn't actually a good idea. I adopted and used `vh` in substitution for `px` since it is based on the current viewport's size and then adjust textbox/img/div or anything that has a `size: ...vh;`

This is actually good but somehow when I try to tap on the textboxes and then the keyboard appears, the stuffs resizes and shrinks down from this:
[image]

To this:
[image]

This somehow never happens on iOS, only on Android phones. (It's probably with Android's keyboard popping out and taking out *real-space* from the browser)

Is there someway to fix this, if not, is there anyway that I can adjust my textboxes/divs that'll still be responsive to any mobile resolutions? Thanks!

Comment: Please check this link [Scalable Density Pixel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44630037/fill-the-dessert-in-my-head-with-dimens-xml/44630670?noredirect=1#comment76386789_44630670)

Comment: and please let us know if it helps or else we will provide some alternate :)

Comment: Refer this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556933/screen-styling-when-virtual-keyboard-is-active

Comment: @jaffarThanks! This actually pretty neat. One thing is that, I actually don't know how to use it, specially in css. And if you could, it would be good to have an alternative way to do it also?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Android keyboard might be consuming real space in the browser, the viewport height decreases causing everything to shrink. In this case, you can use pixels instead of `vh` as I don't think it's important to use `vh`. Using pixels in this case won't affect the site's responsiveness.

You can also check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22627646/how-to-prevent-mobile-keyboard-from-rising-footer-over-the-text-fields) if it helps.